# Dropping column in pandas issue

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is sample of my dataset

```
id   imdb_id  popularity  budget     revenue   cast         runtime
1357 0        3.1         150000000  20000000  Chris Pratt  124
```

and here is my code

```
df.drop(['imdb_id', 'cast', 'runtime'], axis=1 , inplace=True)
```

i got this error

> ValueError: labels ['imdb_id' 'cast', 'runtime'] not contained in axis

Comment: Works fine here. May be there are blank spaces around column names, print df.columns

Answer (score 1):

I noticed a missing `,` in `labels ['imdb_id' 'cast', 'runtime']`.

Could that be the problem?

Otherwise, make sure the names of the columns do not contain white spaces by printing `df.columns`